# Transitioning from Firebase Web to React Native Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, mobile-application, react-native-firebase

I initially used Firebase Web for my React Native app and recently realized that using React Native has several advantages that I need.

If I were to transition then what are the main steps that I would have to take?
What functions are common between the two?
Do I need to make any changes on the Firebase website?

Here are some of the functions I am currently using from Firebase Web:

```js
// Import authentication-related functions from Firebase
import { getAuth } from "@firebase/auth";

// Import cloud storage-related functions from Firebase
import {
  getDownloadURL,
  getStorage,
  ref,
  uploadBytesResumable
} from "firebase/storage";

// Import Firestore related functions and types from Firebase
import {
  DocumentData,
  QueryDocumentSnapshot,
  SnapshotOptions,
  getDoc,
  doc,
  collection,
  where,
  getDocs,
  Timestamp,
  query
} from "firebase/firestore";
```

Still playing with the idea and just want to know if this can be done and how much work it will be